# How do file hashes guarantee files haven't been altered?

Tags: file, security, hash

When downloading files from most trusted sites, they provide hashes for the files that you can then use to authenticate that a file you downloaded is the same one they published (or if I'm wrong in this, please correct me!)

My question is: If you were a hacker capable of modifying a file on a site, couldn't you also alter the page on that site that published the hash values to reflect your new "modified" values?  If so, what added security does it provide?  If not, why not?  Or ... am I just missing something obvious as to how that all works?

Comment: I've made that same point many times to friends, family and clients.  I suppose it's better than nothing, but not much.  In fact, it might be *worse*, because it might lead to a false sense of security.  This is the whole reason for digital signatures.  Unfortunately, many significant vendors and open source projects still provide downloads that aren't digitally signed (sigh).  The overhead of creating a hash is essentially zero.  Apparently the overhead of obtaining a signing certificate, and signing images, is just too much (another sigh...)

Comment: As long as the hash is published on a page that is delivered over https, you can at least be reasonably sure that it was published by the subject of the given certificate. If the attacker can modify files on the site itself, then hashes are useless. I agree with @Dan, signed executable are preferable.

Comment: Hashes have the most added value when the file is also hosted on download mirrors. By supplying the hashes on the main site but the file on different sites, you can make sure that the file from those other sites hasn't been altered. I agree that when they are all hosted on the same site then it has not much added value.

Comment: Thanks everybody (@Dan @user18044 @Rutix) for your answers!  All very good points.  I appreciate you taking the time to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is what attack vector you're protecting against:

1. Someone Breaching The Main Server

   If someone can get in the main server, they can rewrite the hashes to appear valid (so no go).

   So hashes provide no protection against breaches of the main server.
2. Someone Breaching A Mirror Server

   Assuming the hashes are on the main server, then they can add a layer of defense against someone breaching a mirror, as you can detect their modifications.
3. Someone MITM In The Connection

   If someone can MITM the connection, they can modify both the file and the hash.

   So it won't protect you there at all.
4. A bit error in the TCP connection

   This is the prime benefit of hashing files. In the past, when error checking wasn't as good as it is today, you'd download a 100mb file, and there'd be random bit errors in it. An `md5sum` would let you quickly detect those errors and re-download the file.

That's all a hash is good for. Integrity checking that what you downloaded is what was on the server.

If you want security, you need a signature from a trusted private key (GPG). Hashing does nothing for security in the vast majority of cases.